# javafx event.getSource() not working as expected

Tags: javafx, event-handling

I'd like to ask for help with event.getSource(). I've started to learn JavaFx and all instructional videos on internet say do it like this, see basic code.
But, output generated by event.getSource() is just reference to button(Button@4454de36[styleClass=button]'Write') and as such obviously not compared with string in if statement. And as such btn clicks do nothing. What is working solution?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

 
public class HelloWorld extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button btn = new Button("Write");
        
        btn.setOnAction(this);
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println(event.getSource());
        if(event.getSource() == "btn"){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to play with event.getSource(). to somehow separate name of button, but nothing worked. Output is still the same.

Comment: This just isn’t the way to handle events in JavaFX. Use a different event handler for each control (so there is no need to test for the source of the event). Use a lambda expression (or at least an anonymous class) to implement each handler.

Comment: I'm just curious ..why does in this video all work? https://youtu.be/S_JN7zO12H4

Comment: In the video, he compares the event source to the actual button reference, not to the text in the button (or any other `String`). If you do it the same way, it will work. It is a completely unscalable and nonsensical approach though. You should not blindly copy nonsense you find online without critically evaluating it.

Comment: I realized your advice once you said that about String. What he actually does, he sets variable type Button up there. Than he can compare references in handle in if statement, since btn variable is already visible out there. It works now.  Thx. mate for direction.

Comment: *"he can compare references in handle in if statement"* And it should be obvious that this is a terrible approach. Again, don't copy garbage from the internet just because it's on the internet.

Comment: IMO, `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>` on the `extends Application` class is a terrible coding practice.

Comment: Could you be pls more specific why? Just to learn from very beginning as a novice in this field. Why people show this in instr.vids than?...personal preference?

Comment: "_Could you be pls more specific why?_" -- It violates [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) (particularly the single-responsibility principle). The `Application` subclass represents the entire application and its lifecycle. It is not an event handler, and an event handler is not an application. Additionally, event handlers are typically lightweight; they just call some other code that implements the "action" when appropriate. In most cases, it doesn't make sense to have a full-blown class to implement an event handler. Just use a lambda expression or method reference.

Comment: "_Why people show this in instr.vids than?_" -- Could be any number of reasons. Perhaps the instructor is not that great of a software engineer. Perhaps the instructor believes breaking certain "rules" makes it easier to teach a particular concept but failed to clarify that a "rule" was being broken. Perhaps the instructor feels certain concepts are meant to be taught after other more foundational concepts have been taught. Perhaps the instructor is just lazy. Perhaps it's a holdover from tutorials written before Java 8 (which added lambda expressions/method references).

Comment: Or perhaps some other reason I'm not thinking of.

Comment: How would you do it before Java 8, right way? Thx. in advance.

Comment: Before lambda expressions and method references, creating inline event handlers involved using an anonymous class. Anonymous classes are verbose, especially in comparison to lambda expressions method references. So, there was a temptation to have the enclosing class implement event-handler-like interfaces instead of creating multiple anonymous classes, despite doing so was not necessarily best practice.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the video works because it isn't comparing the event source to a String, it is comparing it to a button.

Regardless, the approach is suboptimal, don't write code like this where you implement a switch or test to find the source in an event handler.

You are setting an event handler on a button, so you already know which button the event handler applies to -> you don't need to test to find which button was applied and you don't need to use one event handler for all of your buttons.

Instead, create a new event handler for each button.  This is easily accomplished using a lambda expression:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> doSomething());
```

where `doSomething()` is the name of some method you want to execute when the action is performed.

Eden tutorials explain how to handle button events:

- [JavaFX Button Events and How to Use Them](https://edencoding.com/javafx-button-events-and-how-to-use-them/).

Example code from the eden article (slightly modified):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonEventExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //Create Scene Graph
        Button button = new Button("Press me!");
        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        
        //Define Button Action
        Label label = new Label("Pressed!");
        button.setOnAction(event -> 
            root.getChildren().setAll(label)
        );

        //Create Window
        primaryStage.setTitle("Button Example App");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for link, I'll focus on those tutorials. I'm very beginner in this field, so all valuable infos are welcomed.